# 403 Error page not showing in Symfony

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I am using Symfony 1.4 for onr of my project and it is needed to show a custom 403 error page. I have given the following in settings.yml

```
 .actions:
    error_404_module: errors
    error_404_action: error404
    error_500_module: errors
    error_500_action: error500
    error_403_module: errors
    error_403_action: error403
```

I also have the error modules and corresponding error success pages. But it is not showing the custom error pages. Instaed in some cases for ex: 404 it is showing a debug page . 403 page is returned with a default forbidden error message. My action file is like the following:

```
class errorsActions extends sfActions
{
 /**
  * Executes index action
  *
  * @param sfRequest $request A request object
  */
  public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    //$this->forward('default', 'module');
  }

  public function executeError404(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
  }

  public function executeError500(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
  }
  public function executeError403(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
  }
}
```

EDIT : Adding settings.yml modifications

```
  .actions:
    error_404_module: errors
    error_404_action: error404
    error_500_module: errors
    error_500_action: error500
    secure_module: errors
    secure_action: error403
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case the settings.yml should be:

```
all:
  .actions:
    # page not found
    error_404_module:       errors     # module "errors"
    error_404_action:       error404   # action "executeError404"

    # 403 credential required
    secure_module:          errors     # module "errors"
    secure_action:          error403   # action "executeError403"
```

For the 500 error page, create a directory `error` in your `app/appname/config` directory and put a `error.html.php` file in it (a complete html page).

About the 404 error page, this page (like the 500 error page) is overwritten in the `dev` environment with the debug page but it will show correctly in the `prod` environment.

Comment: do you have tested in `prod` environment?

Answer (score 0):

That is not the correct way to override the 403 error pages. Use `secure_module` and `secure_action`.

Comment: Please put the relevant part of your edited settings.yml in your question. It should be working, so you did not do it correctly.

Comment: I have added now .Also disabled the security settings as mentioned by ivoba

Answer (score 0):

you probably need to unsecure the 404 action:
see here: http://symfony-check.org/permalink/customize-the-oops-page-not-found-page